# How to log float64 on arduino?

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble logging a float64 value. Here's my arduino code (I'm using [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial)):

```
void jt_callback(const trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory &msg) {
  // http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html
  trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint *points = msg.points;  <-- is this correct?
  sprintf(log_msg,"points[0].positions[0] = %f",points[0].positions[0]);  <-- correct?
  nh.loginfo(log_msg);
}
```

Output:

The correct value should be `0.1` not `?`.

Also, when I try `%d` or `%i` the output value is `-13108`.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254960/how-to-log-float64-on-arduino?/) by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed my own problem! I found that I needed to convert float to char* using a function in the standard Arduino library called `dtostrf()`. Think of it as "Decimal to String Float".

This answer has a better description: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/26832/how-do-i-convert-a-float-into-char

Working code:

```
void jt_callback(const trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory &msg) {
  nh.loginfo("msg received");
  // Print points.positions[0]
  char result[8]; // Buffer big enough for 7-character float
  dtostrf(points[0].positions[0], 6, 2, result); // Leave room for too large numbers!
  sprintf(log_msg,"points[0].positions[0] =%s", result);
  nh.loginfo(log_msg);
}
```

Correct output:

---

Originally posted by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) with karma: 203 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3